# Replacement of FB.ui feed to post to other app-user timeline

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-timeline, facebook-ui

I am creating a new facebook web app, in which there's a function allow user to post to other app-user timeline, and here's the code

```
FB.ui({
    api_id: '1234567890',
    method: 'feed',
    link: 'http://www.example.com/fbshare-test/',
    caption: 'Example Test',
    picture: 'http://www.example.com/fbshare-test//img/share.jpg',
    to: '1234567890'
}, function(response){
    console.log(response);
});
```

it works properly. But, referring to facebook official doc, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog/v2.0, the FB.ui.feed is deprecated and replaced by FB.ui.share.

But the new FB.ui.share can't not post to other app-user timeline.

Is there any alt method to replacement my current FB.ui feed function?

Comment: If you want the user to be able to share something with a friend you can use the share dialog

Comment: but the share dialog doesn't let me pre-define the recipient

Comment: Shouldn't the user select who they want to share it with?

Comment: the share dialog can't post to other users' timelines. Only the share button(social plugin) can post to other users' timelines. but I have to trigger the share function automatically instead of by user-click

Comment: I know. I just thought that you wanted to let the user share something with a friend